# Free C++ profiler for Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, profiler

What free profilers are there fore Windows 7 that are compatible with vs2010?

Comment: that thing cost over 1000 us dollars

Comment: If all you want to do is find performance problems, you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had to look for one (because I use MinGW and it has a profiler for free), and I've never used this one before, so I don't know if it has all the features you're looking for, but try this anyway?

[Very Sleepy Profiler](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy)

[Xperf from Windows Performance Analysis Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising if you are looking to import from MSVC

http://www.codeblocks.org/

> Imports MSVC projects and workspaces (NOTE: assembly code not supported yet)